# difference between EndPoint and WebService - Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What is the difference between `@EndPoint` and `@WebService`? Looks like they both are used to define an endpoint which is providing some services to its clients.

```
@WebService
public class Hello {
    //
}
```

and

```
@EndPoint
public class Hello{
    //
}
```

are the same or what difference do they have?

Comment: try http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/114849-endpoint-vs-webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@Endpoint**

`@Endpoint` is from `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint` and indicates that an annotated class is an "Endpoint" (e.g. a web service endpoint). It's used to create a custom endpoint when you are leveraging Spring framework.

**@ WebService**

`@WebService` is from `javax.jws.WebService` and marks a Java class as implementing a Web Service, or a Java interface as defining a Web Service interface. It is defined by JSR-181 which is a standard way of declaring WebService endpoints in the spirit of JavaEE 5+. In case you are using leveraging Spring framework, you cannot use the `@WebService` annotation since Spring can't scan the classes annotated with it or invoke it.

Sources:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jws/WebService.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/annotation/package-summary.html

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/114849-endpoint-vs-webservice